# Creates a class that searches for the elements in a list that contain a sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, search

Not sure what I should write here. The code should be self-explanatory.

```
"""This is a data definition class--Searchable_list.
Searchable_list takes a list of strings and makes it searchable.
Searchable meaning you can find which elements in the list have a pattern.
"""
class Searchable_list(object):
    """this will make your word list searchable.
Note, It will also loose the original order of the list."""
    def __init__(self, lis):
        assert hasattr(lis,"__iter__")
        self.search_dict=dict()
        for word in set(lis):self.add_word(word)

    def add_word(self,word):
        """this will add a word to the search_dict
search dict is of the form: {letter:{nextletter:{(index,word)}}}
"""
        assert type(word) is str#or isinstance(word,str)
        for index,val in enumerate(word[:-1]):
            next_letter=self.search_dict.setdefault(val,dict())
            words_list=next_letter.setdefault(word[index+1],set())#object modification
            words_list.add((index,word))#object modifification

    def find_matches(self,seq):
        """finds all the words in the list with this sequence.
Uses '.' as wildcard.
"""
        s_d=self.search_dict
        assert len(seq)>1
        #could put a try catch to catch key errors
        for index,letter in enumerate(seq[:-1]):
            if not(letter=="."and seq[index+1]=="."):
                #no point if they all match...
                if letter==".":
                    L_m=set.union(*(i.get(seq[index+1],set()) for i in s_d.values()))
                    #.get is important here. not all is have i[seq[index+1]]
                elif seq[index+1]==".":
                    L_m=set.union(*(i for i in s_d[letter].values()))
                else:
                    L_m=s_d[letter].get(seq[index+1],{})#this is a set.
                #L_m==letter_matches
                if index>0:
                    m_m=((i-index,word) for i,word in L_m)
                    #m_m=matches_matches. These words still have the pattern.
                    #your matching all indexes to the original m_s
                    m_s.intersection_update(m_m)
                    #m_s=matches_set
                else:
                    m_s=L_m.copy()
                    #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200969/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-set-in-python
        return m_s
```

EDIT: Because this post was bumped, and I've added some pretty major improvements to it here's a link to the final version of this. It's not very clean, but it has optimizations this doesn't have. If there's an interest I can try to put some comments explaining the optimizations in the github or post something here about it (probably in the form of another answer). https://github.com/user-name-is-taken/words-with-friends/blob/master/WWF_DDC.py (note, the scrabble stuff is just adapting this code for scrabble). For now, the basic idea behind the optimizations is that python's set.intersection is faster than set.union

Comment: "Not sure what I should write here." Does it work as intended? Do you want a review about any and all aspects of your code? If you can answer both questions with 'yes', you probably posted in the right place. Of-course, you could always check the [help/on-topic].

Comment: I can answer yes to both.

Answer (score 1):

## naming

Based on reading your comment, I propose this name:

```
class SearchableCollection(object):
```

Rely on duck typing, rather than trying to write java code in python:

```
def __init__(self, words):
    # (delete this line) assert hasattr(lis,"__iter__")
    self.words = {}
    for word in words:
        self._add_word(word)
```

It appears that add_word is not part of your public API. Mark it so with a leading underscore, or make it a nested `def`. Do not assert that type is str.

```
    for index,val in enumerate(word[:-1]):
```

Please name it `letter` rather than the very vague `val`. Or `cur_letter`, parallel with `next_letter`.

You are using `setdefault()` in a sensible way. But you might be happier using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

You named it `words_list`, but apparently you meant `words_set`.

## style

Run `$ flake8 WWF_DDC.py` and follow its advice, please.

Answer (score 0):

Just an updated version of find matches. Changes are:

- I added a while loop that removes trailing "."s see the comments for an explanation.
- And, I moved the intersection out of the loop for speed and to make the code cleaner. This required adding the setsList list.

```
    def find_matches(self,seq):
        """finds all the words in the list with this sequence.
Uses '.' as wildcard.
"""
        assert len(seq)>1        
        s_d = self.search_dict
        setsList =[]
        while seq[-1]=='.':
            #not solved by if index+1=='.' because there's no [letter][''] for word endings in self.search_dict.
            #without this, .f. wouldn't find (0,"of"), because the L_m in the seq[index+1]=="." if wouldn't include it.
            seq = seq[:-1]
        for index,letter in enumerate(seq[:-1]):
            if not(letter=="." and seq[index+1]=="."):#no point if they all match...
                if letter==".":
                    L_m = set.union(*(i.get(seq[index+1],set()) for i in s_d.values()))
                    #.get is important here. not all is have i[seq[index+1]]
                elif seq[index+1]==".":
                    L_m = set.union(*s_d[letter].values())
                else:
                    L_m = s_d[letter].get(seq[index+1],{})#this is a set.
                    #not using s_d.get could cause errors here...
                #L_m==letter_matches
                setsList.append({(i-index,word) for i,word in L_m})
        return set.intersection(*setsList)
```